# Coldfusion 9 Deploy WAR file

Tags: coldfusion, war, coldfusion-9

in Coldfusion 9, Currently we are deploying CFM/CFC files to IIS webroot and exploring options to deploy the code as WAR file.

Can someone help me with steps to follow.

Comment: Did you google something like "coldfusion 9 war deployment", and did none of the material listed there help you *at all*?

Comment: Even googling the title that you gave this question leads you directly to the documentation for it - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Installing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cdec18c28-7fda.html

Comment: The document explains how to build the CF server as WAR file, but i am more interested in knowing how to convert CF code into WAR file and deploy it on to an existing CF 9 server and IIS 7

Comment: There is no _converting_ of code.  A WAR file is simply an ARchive (collection) of files.